# Equivalent to "nested match" in Rust

Tags: functional-programming, rust, purely-functional

I'm trying to implement a purely functional red-black tree in Rust, following Okasaki's example. When I insert into a red-black tree, I might have to insert into the tree. Here's Haskell code for the `balance` function:

```hs
balance :: Ord a => Color -> Tree a -> a -> Tree a -> Tree a
balance Black (T Red (T Red a x b) y c) z d = T Red (T Black a x b) y (T Black c z d)
balance Black (T Red a x (T Red b y c)) z d = T Red (T Black a x b) y (T Black c z d)
balance Black a x (T Red (T Red b y c) z d) = T Red (T Black a x b) y (T Black c z d)
balance Black a x (T Red b y (T Red c z d)) = T Red (T Black a x b) y (T Black c z d)
balance c l v r = T c l v r
```

This code uses nested matching. However, this is not possible in Rust as one has to use a "boxed" representation for the left and right branches. I'm using an `Rc`. Here's my data definition for `Tree<A>`:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
enum Tree<A> {
    E,
    T(Color, Rc<Tree<A>>, A, Rc<Tree<A>>)
}
```

How can I achieve the equivalent of "nested matching" when I have `Rc`s?

**I am well aware that it is impossible to match into `Rc`s**. Instead, I am wondering if there are equivalent programming idioms that can achieve the same effect.